# How to reset perspective programmatically in Eclipse RCP E4 not E3

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, e4

I just added 2 perspectives in my RCP App. I can switch from one to another without problems.

But I didn't find a way to reset perspective, for example if I close a Part excidently I need to reset my perspective.

1. `PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().resetPerspective();`

this didn't work because I use E4.

2. `-clearPersistedState -persistState false`

is not a solution cause I need to reset without restart my App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `resetPerspective` method of `EModelService`:

```
public void resetPerspectiveModel(MPerspective persp, MWindow window)
```

Note that `PlatformUI` and associated APIs can't be used in a pure e4 application.

Comment: I tried the following but it didn't do anything: `MPerspective currentPerspective = (MPerspective) modelService.find(PERSPECTIVE_ID, application); MWindow window = application.getChildren().get(0); modelService.resetPerspectiveModel(currentPerspective, window);`